# Consistent update UITableview after Coredata updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, asynchronous, delegates

I have an application that uses coredata. The Download of data happens in a class A. Coredata updates/saves/deletes are in the SharedDelegate (B). The delegate initiates the download in A and implements its protocol to get notified when a download was completed, so the delegate can update its data in the database.

Now, after that happened, I would like the class C, that has the UITableview, to update its rows and cells so I can show the new content.

How would I correctly notifly C, that it can update its table? What are the possible errors that can occur?

The download and update happens asynchronously of course and so far, I update only after ALL downloads have been completed.... I would like to split the task, so to say.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use an `NSFetchedResultsController` as the table view's data source. The documentation for `NSFetchedResultsController` contains a lot of code that you can copy & paste into your app to manage table view updates whenever the managed object context changes.
2. Register for the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. In your notification method, handle the cases  `NSInsertedObjectsKey`, `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`, and `NSDeletedObjectsKey` and update your table view accordingly.

Comment: this sounds promising, will try both. Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNotificationCenter`.  Set the class C to listen for notifications and reload the data accordingly.  When the SharedDelegate B updates the data, post a notification.